# Find pipeline-variables for a Bitbucket pipeline

Tags: pipeline, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm taking over some code, where I can see a line like this in the `bitbucket-pipeline.yaml`-file:

```
if [ $THEME_NAME ]; then cd ./site/web/app/themes/$THEME_NAME/ && yarn && cd ../../../../../trellis; else cd ./trellis; fi
```

But I've searched the code base for `$THEME_NAME` and `THEME_NAME` and this is the only place it's referenced.

As you can probably see, then it's built using [Trellis](https://roots.io/trellis/), which is built on top of WordPress. So maybe it's a global variable.

How do I figure out, where this (and other) variable resolves to?

**Solution-thoughts:**

The quick'n'dirty way would be to simply add a step in the pipeline that echo's all the global variables, but it seems yucky, since I would have to remove that commit again, and have to make the bash-script that did this, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The quick'n'dirty way was answered here: [Dump all variables for bash](https://askubuntu.com/a/275972/332403)

So by adding `printenv` to a pipeline step and commit it.

---

In this specific case (being a Bitbucket-pipeline), I could find the answer here: [Variables and secrets](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/variables-and-secrets/)

Find it under: Settings >> Repository variables.